# how to sort a mixed string with numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of strings:

```
l = ['img1','img2','img11','img3']
```

I tried this:

```
l.sort()
>>>['img1', 'img11', 'img2', 'img3']
```

but the result is not what I want.
how can I sort the list so that i get the results below:

```
['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img11']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` feature in the `sorted` method. Here `re` is used to get the integer from the string.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
Out[2]: ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img11']
```